# Does sharing code on Arduino Create automatically grant any license rights?

Tags: arduino-ide

I have code I am happy to share under a GNU GPL License and which is marked accordingly. Before I upload it to Arduino Create Web Editor I want to check whether in doing so I inadvertently grant additional license rights. I have searched for any terms and conditions which may inform me but not found any as yet.

Answer (score 1):

Arduino Create doesn't assume any licensing of any form. Sharing isn't a public thing. You have to specifically provide someone with a link to your sketch. If you choose to post that link publicly then that is your concern.

Any licensing should be included with your sketch.

Answer (score -2):

You should read the [GPL License terms](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) with respect to any rights you are concerned about, but in general, GPL licensed software is available to anyone to do anything with, as long as they keep it public and perpetuate the GPL License. Note: IANALawyer. If you wish to protect any specific rights, you should probably consult one.